# PriorityQueue is Java does not order descending with custom comparator

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I'm implementing a sample order book (in Exchange domain) and I'm implementing the buy and the sell sides using PriorityQueue in Java.

Buy side should be descending and **sell side should be ascending**.

```
PriorityQueue<ArrayList<Order>> bookSide;
```

Each side consists of price points, and each point has a list of Orders.

[image: Buy/Sell Side]

My buy side works fine.

This is my sell side. I want this is to be ordered descending.

```
sellSide = new PriorityQueue<ArrayList<Order>>(new Comparator<ArrayList<Order>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<Order> arg0, ArrayList<Order> arg1) {
        // below two conditions are highly unlikely to happen
        // as the the elements are added to the list before the list is
        // added to the queue.
        if (arg0.size() == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (arg1.size() == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        // all the elements in a list have a similar price
        Order o1 = arg0.get(0); 
        Order o2 = arg1.get(0);
        int r = (int) (o1.getPrice() - o2.getPrice());
        return  r;

    }

});
```

I add 100,100,101 and 99.

When 101 is added, it correctly adds 101 below 100 (list of 100). But when I add 99, it destroys the order and becomes 99,101,100.

I have no clue what is wrong.

Please help me out.

**EDIT**

This is how I add the elements to the lists. The `price` is a `long`.

```
ArrayList<Order> pricePoint = sidePoints.get(price);
if (pricePoint == null) {
    pricePoint = new ArrayList<>();
    pricePoint.add(order); // I want the list to be non-empty when adding to queue
    bookSide.add(pricePoint);
} else {
    pricePoint.add(order);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the only issue, but your `compare` method violates the contract of the `Comparator` interface.

Comment: @Eran : Please tell me how.

Comment: You add the elements of the order to what? To the lists? If so: `PriorityQueue` will not magically re-order itself when you change the contained `ArrayList`s, it assumes constant elements. Side notes: If `arg0.size() == arg1.size() == 0`, you return `-1` instead of `0`. [`Comparator.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) is only allowed to return `-1`, `0`, and `1`.

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris If one of the lists is empty, you always return -1, however the sign of compare(x,y) must be - the sign of compare(y,x).

Comment: please show how you populate the lists and the priority queue.

Comment: @dhke : The ArrayList always have the elements with the same value (price). So, it doesn't matter the contents of the ArrayList changes. And, I'm deleting the ArrayList whenever it gets empty. So, I want to get the correct position only when it gets added.

And, arg0 and arg1 with never be empty. So, we can ignore that condition there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there's a misunderstanding about how `PriorityQueue` works.
Let's try to clear that up.

> But when I add 99, it destroys the order and becomes 99,101,100.

First, an important reminder from the [Javadoc of `PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap.

The key term here is *heap*.
In a heap, elements are not ordered in a sequence.
A heap is a tree-like structure,
where every node is consistently ordered compared to every other node *below* it.
In other words,
there are no guarantees whatsoever with respect to ordering of nodes at the same level.

A heap in ascending order (min heap) will guarantee that the top element is the smallest.
After you pop the top element,
the next top element will be the smallest of the remaining elements.
And so on.

If you want a list of sorted elements,
you have to build it by popping from the heap one by one.
Alternatively,
you can use just a list,
and sort it using `Collections.sort`.

---

As an aside,
and as others pointed out in comments,
the implementation of the compare method violates the contract of the `Comparator` interface:
when precisely one of `a` and `b` is empty,
both `compare(a, b)` and `compare(b, a)` returns -1,
which implies that `a < b` and `b < a`,
which breaks logic.

The fix is easy, I also simplified a bit the rest of the implementation:

```
@Override
public int compare(ArrayList<Order> arg0, ArrayList<Order> arg1) {
  if (arg0.isEmpty()) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (arg1.isEmpty()) {
    return 1;
  }

  return Integer.compare(arg0.get(0).getPrice(), arg1.get(0).getPrice());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But your compare method still does not solve my problem. :(

Comment: And I want a list of lists, which is sorted according to the first element of the each list.

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris my main point, and the key to the solution, is the discussion about heap, in the beginning of my question. It seems you still don't get it. Let's try to figure this out. What exactly do you mean when you say in your post "But when I add 99, it destroys the order and becomes 99,101,100." ?

Comment: Hi, I found where the error was. It seems accessing the elements of a PriorityQueue using a for-each loop does not give us the correct order. Thanks.